# Using Django Endless Pagination with Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-masonry, django-endless-pagination

I am trying to use [Django Endless Pagination](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

The problem I keep on having is, that Masonry works just fine for the first page, but when new data is populated in the page, masonry does not apply to the new loaded elements. I looked into [adding items](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html) but I dont think that would help me in this case.

So is their a way to re-initialize masonry once the new elements are loaded?

I was just wondering if anyone else had a similar issue, and if someone has the solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone has a similar issue, I finally found the solution. I ended up using `.masonry('reload')`.
After endless_on_scroll, its easier to just call the reload function again. it takes care of the problem!

Comment: how and where you have added. Could you please add a snippet of code. I am stuck with same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Django-Endless-Pagination has an `onCompleted` callback in its settings. In there, do the following:

```
var masonry = $(myMasonryObject).data('masonry');
if (masonry !== undefined) {
    masonry.reloadItems();
    masonry.layout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the decision above I found some issue. When i'm scroll to the end of page, i saw some artifacts (items are superimposed on each other or on footer).

I think, it's because we are calling masonry.reloadItems () before images loaded or something else and items does not have it's real size yet.

This solutions can fix this issue:

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
    $.endlessPaginate({
      paginateOnScroll: true,
      paginateOnScrollMargin: 3840,
      onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var gallery = $('.gallery');
            gallery.imagesLoaded(function () {
                var masonry = gallery.data('masonry');
                if (masonry !== undefined) {
                    masonry.reloadItems();
                    masonry.layout();
                }
            });
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```